# How to revert a persistent Delegate ModelIndex back to "normal"

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qmodelindex

Once a delegate item has been set as persistent using:

`tableView.openPersistentEditor(model.index(0, 0))`

would it be possible to revert it back to "unpersistent" (irresolute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [closePersistentEditor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#closePersistentEditor) to close the persistent editor at a given index :

```
tableView.closePersistentEditor(model.index(0, 0))
```